# Parallel.Foreach and WriteAsync to improve performance?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel.foreach

I have written the following codes in C# which I am looking for tips on improvement.

I have used Parallel.ForEach() to help parallelize the work needed.

What this does is to loop through a list of "students". For each student, it will go through the text file associated with that student and do calculations. Afterwards, it appends the result to the "outputLines" and then output the whole result at the end for each student.

Two things I have tried that helps me identify the bottleneck of running the program:

1. If I only do the calculation and add the result to "outputLines" and "outputLine2", the time taken would be approximately 3 seconds.
2. If I write the "outputLines" and "outputLines2" to different files as shown in the codes below, the time taken would have increased significantly to 1 minute 30 seconds.

3 seconds and 1.5 minutes here are only for this small sample of students. In fact, I need to go through many more students' files to do the work. In the actual project, the time taken for the "no writing to file" takes 5 minutes to complete, and "writing to file" takes 1 hour for completion.

I am new to async, and wonder if anyone can tell me where and how I could improve the performance of this prorgram if I were to write the output asynchronously. In the codes below, I have only used File.WriteAllLines() to do the writing work.

Please let me know how I could amend the codes to improve the performance.

```
    private void generateFiles()
    {
        List<string> students = new List<string>();

        students.Add("Peter");
        students.Add("James");
        students.Add("Sarah");

        // There are more than 100 students in this case, which I have removed them here for the sake of brevity.



        Parallel.ForEach(students, student =>
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(@"C:\", student + ".txt"));
            List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();
            List<string> outputLines2 = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // for each "line", we process something and then add the result to "outputLines" and "outputLines2"
                // outputLines.Add(result)
                // outputLines2.Add(result)

            }

            File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(@"C:\Output\", student + ".txt"), outputLines);
            File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(@"C:\Output2\", student + ".txt"), outputLines2);

        });

    }
```

Comment: You can test with a profiler where the bottleneck is. Once you know, you can improve it (or ask here a question how to improve it if you don't know).

Comment: And async programming does not improve performance. It can make your app feel more responsive, but that's different. Anyway, the work has to be done.

Comment: @Sjips I think I have done similar steps as you suggested. I have tried removing the last two lines (File.WriteAllLines) and then the  time taken in the sample 50 students version went down from 1m30s to 3s. Hence, I believe the bottleneck is right over there and so I am asking for improvement tips over here. Or anything in general.

Comment: Do you have a very slow harddrive? It seems your bottleneck is writing the data to disk? I propose you gather ALL the data, then write each file ONE at at time. The reason is probably IO and multiple file writings at the same time.

Comment: It would point to the `File.WriteAllLines` function. That's hard to improve. But if you remove the last 2 lines, it could also be possible that the compiler is optimizing your code and does nothing in the body of your code (in your example: the part in the for-each).

Comment: If you replace TEMPORARY the lines by `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"C:\Output\", student + ".txt"), outputLines[0]);` (and second line) you can quickly verify if your harddrive is too slow (because only one line is written and less bytes is written to the HD). If the code runs very fast now, your HD is probably the problem. If it is comparable, then it is some other problem.

Comment: I do not believe ReadAllLines actually reads the whole file at once. It reads it line by line as you ask for the lines, so unless you actually use the data, the compiler might have optimized the whole file reading away?...

Comment: I have replace TEMPORARILY the lines by File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"C:\Output\", student + ".txt"), outputLines[0]); The time taken drops to 20s. I have used a SSD in this case already. So is there any chance that I can still improve this?

Comment: You dont by chance have a faulty SSD. The Samsung EVO series that lately has been mentioned that needs to get an updated firmware.

Comment: Not likely. I am using 840 PRO and its on the latest firmware.

Comment: So: no file: 3 s; file with 1 line: 20 s; file with all lines: 90 s. So it looks like the file writing is the issue. Because the files have to be written to 1 drive, I don't think Parallel.For is favorable in your case, or will give you much improvement. Note that writing a lot of small files is worse than writing a small number of big files (in the latter case, an SSD will really help).

Comment: Yes the stats are correct. Yes it's true that there are many small files (1.5MB each) to be written. So in general, there is no way to further improve this program?

Comment: Try writing the files one after each other instead of in parallel. See if it is faster.

Comment: I'm afraid not. However I read this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4aa0fb0-0a36-4884-9fe9-30cbd51639e0/using-filewritealltext-vrs-a-streamwriter?forum=vbgeneral . `WriteAllText` seems to create temporary files. Sounds strange to me, but in that case not using `WriteAllText` but an own implementation using `StreamWriter` and to write the strings could help. But I doubt that it is possible to write an own implementation that can win from `WriteAllText`.

Comment: It was "temporary strings" not files :). Unless the OP has a very slow system and little RAM it would not be noticable.

Comment: But the comment about the `Encoding type` makes sense. When all the strings (all double-byte characters) have to be converted to UTF8 first (because that is the default encoding for WriteAllText) it might impact your performance. Maybe try to add `Encoding.Unicode` as the third parameter might help.

Comment: Doing file I/O in parallel is a pretty standard mistake.  Unlike a multi-core processor, you have only one disk and it can do only one thing at a time.  It gets very, very grouchy if you force it to do multiple things at the same time, seeks are very expensive.  Even on an SSD.

Comment: I have my finger on IO performance on this topic. The Encoding should have a very small footprint unless he is running it on a 286 computer. Or there is a big bug in the .Net framework.

Comment: Saving data in Unicode instead of UTF8 saves the conversion, but you have to write the double amount of bytes...Maybe it was not a good statement after all.  I think Hans has right: at the end you have a single HDD where all the writes come together.